# How to get kubenetes cluster's metrics such as Memory CPU and so on using JAVA client

Tags: java, kubernetes, metrics

I am using [official java client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java) of Kubernetes to request resources of the cluster such as Pods, Deployment and so on.

But unfortunately I found that it seems there is no API to request cluster metrics such as total CPU and Memory used by all pods.

Do you know how to get the cluster metrics using Java client ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Deploy the [metrics-server](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server) to the cluster.

You will then have access to query the `metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1` API for `pods` and `nodes` as normal kubernetes resource. You should be able to run `kubectl top pod` to test.

I don't see any reason why the official java client wouldn't be able to discover these resources, but if it did they are available at the following URL's

```
https://api-server/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/pods
https://api-server/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/nodes
```

Answer (score 0):

Think you won't be able to this with [official java client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java).

Instead of this you can set up [prometheus](https://prometheus.io/), configure it to scrape metrics and use [Prometheus HTTP API](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/) to get API response in JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

I get the resource consumption for each node using kubectl top api, and add them up.

```
import static io.kubernetes.client.extended.kubectl.Kubectl.top;
import io.kubernetes.client.custom.NodeMetrics;
import io.kubernetes.client.openapi.models.V1Node;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair;

List<Pair<V1Node, NodeMetrics>> nodesMetrics = top(V1Node.class, NodeMetrics.class).apiClient(client).metric("cpu").execute();
```

Maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.kubernetes</groupId>
        <artifactId>client-java</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.kubernetes</groupId>
        <artifactId>client-java-extended</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```